# "USB boot" option not working

Tags: windows, boot, usb

I have an "Ilife zedbook wifi" tablet. I went into its bios and enabled USB boot. I burned windows version 1709 on the USB with rufus because 1803 isn't working too well for me and the tablet isn't letting me update. I have confirmed that the usb does work.

Comment: Please try the current build and if making the USB in another Windows then there's no reason to use Rufus in lie of the official Media Creation Tool. With Rufus, depending on the settings it may only boot in UEFI or BIOS, not both.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how the media is formatted for setup (what partition table, target BIOS type), some media can't be booted. I ran into this problem trying to boot Ubuntu when my computer *strictly* respected UEFI, not UEFI+Legacy or Legacy. Make sure within Rufus that the `Target system` is your BIOS type, whether it be UEFI or Legacy. Your device may not be compatible with the format.

**Legacy is used to refer to the type of BIOS that's used for computers in certain environments/eras, simply known as BIOS. UEFI refers to the UEFI type BIOS.